# Unexpected cast of `Button`

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying to write an Android Studio `java` based program. In which I wanted to display a `button` whoes ID is startButton.It will be nice and I request you whoever watching this
question try to understand my problem and answer it.
The problem is that when I declared a variable called startButton as a `Button type` it showing we a problem tha Unexpected cast of `Button`.

```
package com.green.numbergames;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button startButton;
    public void start(View view){


    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your activity_main xml file

Comment: Please show activity_main.xml content and Error content.